# How to set Foxx App at server root?

Tags: arangodb, foxx

I was wondering how to set a Foxx app at the root of the sever/ip/domain name?

For example if my IP was `100.12.32.12`  if I go to `http://100.12.32.12` it'll open the single-page foxx app without URL redirection.

**Things I've Tried**

1. Currently I got Arangodb to use `tcp://0.0.0.0:80` endpoint, so I got the port to work.
2. I also set up a `index.html` file in my app's `manifest.json` and mounted that app to `/`

   However currently going to `http://100.12.32.12`  redirects me to `http://107.170.131.61/_db/_system/index.html` which works, but URL is changed.

   Also `http://100.12.32.12/index.html` works, but I was wondering if it's possible to get `http://100.12.32.12` to show the app without the redirect.
3. I've tried `sudo arangod --javascript.app-path /path/to/app` but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks. I am new to Arangodb and Foxx.

Comment: Are you exposing ArangoDB directly to the NET or are using it behind a web-server like Apache?

Comment: exposing it on port 80 ... I was hoping to only have to use Foxx/Arangodb for my spa

Comment: Ok, understood. I will ask my colleagues.

Comment: @fceller thanks :) If this isn't intended use, I can keep arango on default port 8529, and fire up an express sever on port 80...

Answer (score 3):

Can you try the following? Open an arangosh in a terminal window or go to the JS shell in the GUI.

```
arangosh [_system]> db._routing.save({ url: "/", priority: 1, action: {do: "org/arangodb/actions/redirectRequest", options: {permanently: true, destination: "/index.html" } } })
{ 
  "error" : false, 
  "_id" : "_routing/87048615", 
  "_rev" : "87048615", 
  "_key" : "87048615" 
}
```

Restart the server (it needs to reload the now routing). Clear/Restart the browser (for chrome you might need to forget the visited sites). Check using telnet

```
> telnet localhost 8529
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved
location: http://localhost:8529/index.html
server: ArangoDB
content-type: text/html
connection: Keep-Alive
content-length: 183

<html><head><title>Moved</title></head><body><h1>Moved</h1><p>This page has moved to <a href="http://localhost:8529/index.html">http://localhost:8529/index.html</a>.</p></body></html>
```

If you do not see the correct address, check if the document was created in _routing correctly.

Now check with the browser. If this still shows the wrong redirect, flush the browser cache.

Comment: thanks, the redirect works, but the URL still changes to index.html Is there anyway to not have the URL change?

Comment: With ArangoDB 2.1 RC2 you will be able to do   db._routing.save({ url: "/", priority: 1, action: {do: "org/arangodb/actions/rewriteRequest", options: {destination: "/index.html" } } })  Either use GITHUB or https://www.arangodb.org/download2

Comment: Thanks! I'll be waiting with anticipation.